# Como criar categoria dinamina com input text

Tags: php, html

Como eu poderia criar uma categoria no select de tipo input text que ao selecionar eu podesse escrever uma observação no pedido. Tipo tenho varias categorias como mostra a imagem abaixo e ao selecionar uma aparece o itens para ser pedido e quando clico ele vai para a tabela de pedido , mas eu gostaria de criar um categoria de input text também , como poderia fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você queria que toda vez que preenche-se o input text, ele criasse uma nova categoria?

Comment: @MaxRogério Não ao seleciona uma categoria com o nome obs por exemple abrisse um input text para insetir alguma observação .